# How to rank subscription plans using Apple In-App Purchase in same subscription group?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

We are trying to upgrade and downgrade subscription plans in apple in-app purchase.
All plans are in one subscription group having different prices and duration.

Our app has in-app purchases with auto-renewable subscriptions.
After buying subscription
1- I chose to downgrade to another product
I got a popup asking me to do I want to upgrade and will get a refund. I press confirm

2-After some time, I chose to upgrade to a higher subscription
I got a popup asking me to do I want to modify my subscription and subscription plan will begin and you will be charged when the current subscription expires

We have followed the below document.
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#ranking

Still, We are a bit unclear about the apple developer document regarding subscription plan ranking.

Can anyone suggest, how to set the rank to a subscription plan?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store questions are considered off-topic, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Can you provide the upgrade/downgrade popop showing code? I tried different ways, it always takes me as a new payment instead of an upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you've configured your subscriptions in the wrong order since an upgrade should cancel immediately your current subscription, whereas a downgrade should wait for the next renewal date.

Here is an example of configuration:

[image: subscription group configuration]

Where the higher plan is "Gold".

So:

- when you change from Silver to Bronze, you have to wait until the next renewal date
- when you change from Silver to Gold, your subscription is immediately canceled and changed into Gold

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain one more case? Let's assume the Gold Plan is 1Month and the Bronze Plan duration is 1 Year. Then will it be considered as an upgrade case or a downgrade case in the apple platform?

Comment: Apple doesn't consider the duration of your plans to trigger different behaviours, it only looks for the order. So here, even if Gold were 1-month-long, and Silver 1-year-long, changing from Silver to Gold would be considered as an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Since this is a server side setting, do changes take effect for apps that are already released? Or is a new version necessary? Anyone know?

Comment: I don't think so (since we can add products without releasing), but I never tried to change the order per say. If you do it, I'm curious to know the actual behaviour.

Comment: It worked! The problem was identified when the customer got a message saying that their "Gold" subscription wouldn't kick in until the "Silver" subscription expired. After putting "Gold" above "Silver", the problem was fixed w/o pushing a new version.